# Can't locate mysql.sock

Tags: mysql

I installed `mysql` under Red Hat Linux 6.7 and when i try to run `mysql` command it shows me this message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So i tried to find mysql.sock under `/var/lib/mysql` and it is not there. Then i searched for the file from the root directory and again nothing. And it seems everything is configured to be working with that non existing file like `/etc/my.cnf` in which the socket is configured to this directory. I'm sure mysql is installed cause when i run `mysql --version` it shows:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

So what should i do to make it work?

Comment: have you tried to restart mysql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm sure mysql is installed cause when i run mysql --version

That just tells you about the mysql command line *client* application.

It says nothing about the mysql *server* which you need to make sure is installed and running.

```
yum install mysql-server
/sbin/service mysqld start
```